# Hiding database format

Tags: database, security, ms-access

I have an application, the databases are in Access.  My software protection is highly dependent on the password I have set for my databases.  If someone gets the password, you can crack the application.

I just found an application over internet (free ware, easily downloadable) which give you Access database password.  This is really worrysome for me.

Is there any way that I could hide my database format so the user who installs the application can not know what format these files are?

Comment: You cannot use Access as your database on a local hard drive and expect it to be 100% secured.  As you found out, it can be hacked open.

Comment: Security by obscurity is no security at all.

Comment: If you keep the key in your application, then it doesn't matter how you obfuscate the DB format - the hacker will just pick the key out from your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the database type you use, the fact is that the password will be in your application *somewhere*.  Sure, it takes a little more to dig that out but there are a whole lot of people that enjoy doing it for "fun".

Which means, as long as the data is local then it will be accessible by any half way determined hacker.  And yes, there are plenty of sites that offer walk throughs on how to extract secret info from your compiled binaries.

So, this leaves you with a quandry.  As long as the app is locally installed, you'll have to come up with a reason for them to either not bother OR a way to detect unauthorized usage.  The former is generally easier than the latter.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious way to obfuscate the DB format would be changing the file extension, but as I said in my comment relying on obfuscation for security is not that effective. The trouble is, if you go further to obscure the DB format then you risk making it unreadable by the Jet database drivers and thus unusable. In short, you are barking up the wrong tree.

You need to either use a different database if you aren't confident in Access security or find a way to make the password more difficult to crack using those utilities.

Not sure which utility you are talking about, but the one I found with a quick Google search has some limitations that you could take advantage of to secure the DB from the use of that tool:

> - In Access 2000/XP files, this utility cannot recover passwords that    contains more than 18 characters.
> - This utility shows only the main database password. It cannot recover    the user-level passwords.

Have you considered just making a really long password and see if you can still crack it with the utility you are worried about?

Also, I'd suggest using the newer ACCDB format instead of MDB as the security has been hardened somewhat.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest encrypting and signing / hashing everthing you put into the db, everything outside your app will be easily broken and even your app may be decompiled if there is something to gain for "THEM".

Comment: Putting the PW on the file automatically encrypts the DB, so this would be embedding encryption inside encryption, but I do see where you are going with this. For performance reasons, he might be better off just encrypting the sensitive stuff in the DB for the inner layer though.

Comment: Yo dawg,  I heard if you put and encryption in your encryption then you can decrypt while you decrypt.   Also i gave you a -1,  because you have no idea what you are suggesting.  This is not a problem that cryptography can solve.

Comment: @Rook Yes, feel free to downvote anything that sounds stupid to you. Would you like to help us with your broad knowledge here? It seems my browser fails to show your perfect answer on this topic...

Comment: @Stephan B  To me it is very obvious.  The OP hasn't a clue what security is and made a fatal mistake.  Clearly cryptography cannot be used because there is no place to a hide a secret key.  If its in memory a debugger can find it.